# How can I reach a Property from String in C#?

Tags: c#, string, properties

I have a two class that response and request. I am getting properties from web in response for set them next step in request. For example

```
private List<ControlInfo> _firmcontrolInfo;
    public List<ControlInfo> FirmControlInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _firmcontrolInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty<List<ControlInfo>>(ref _firmcontrolInfo, value, "FirmControlInfo");
        }
    }

public class ControlInfo : BaseCommonModel<string>
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string ControlName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int ControlLength { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using this for fill request but it is static. I have to find a dynamic way to reach request's propertis from FirmControlInfo's ControlNames(string). This is my static code;

```
if (FirmControlInfo[0].ControlName.Equals("ABNO1"))
                    request.ABNO1 = AbNoSub;
                else if (FirmControlInfo[0].ControlName.Equals("ABNO"))
                    request.ABNO = AbNoSub;
                if (FirmControlInfo[1].ControlName.Equals("ABNO2"))
                    request.ABNO2 = AbNoRegi;
                else if (FirmControlInfo[1].ControlName.Equals("SICNO"))
                    request.SICNO = AbNoRegi;
```

I hope, I describe what I want. 
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish, at first you talk about member number 2 and 5 and the next thing you are talking about member number 1 and 5. Could you please explain a bit better what you are trying to do? Also, post code on what you already have tried.

Comment: Can't say I understand the question, but it seems you are using Json.NET. If the text you receive is a json string, why not simply deserialize it, eg. with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseViewModel1>(output)` ? Please post the code that actually tries the deserialization.

Comment: I have changed description.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with this code in Portable Class;

```
foreach (var item in FirmControlInfo)
            {
                var propInfo = System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeProperties(typeof(RequestViewModel1)).Where(pi => pi.Name == item.ControlName).First();
                propInfo.SetValue(request, AbNoSub);
            }
```

Thanks.